# updated from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and now my django project is not working

Tags: python, django

when I activate my virtual environment and enter **python manage.py runserver** it gives me following error:

```
(myenv) nouman@nouman-G3:~/Documents/test/myshop$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 12, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

I even tried with 'python3' but still doesn't work

Comment: Start with basics: Do you have the `python-django` package installed? (note that your output asked you this question)

Comment: yes I installed Django

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I solved this by deleting my virtual environment folder and all the libraries and 3rd party apps that I was using then I created new virtual environment and installed everything from my requirements.txt file again